# Chrome extension: sendMessage from content to background getting response from popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to send a message from a content script to my background script. When the background receives the message it sends data back to the content script in the callback.

My popup also has a listener for messages from the content script, but does not respond to a message meant for the background script.

Then content is receiving an `undefined` back from the callback, which I think is caused by the popup receiving the message but not responding.

The reference says:

> Note: If multiple pages are listening for onMessage events, only the
>   first to call sendResponse() for a particular event will succeed in
>   sending the response. All other responses to that event will be
>   ignored.

So surely I should only get the response from my background script.

My content script does this:

```
function notifyReady() {

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        type: 'ACTIVITY_HISTORY_READY'
    },
        function (response) {
            console.log(">>>>Response: ", response);
            if (response.type == 'HISTORY_DATA') {
                processLog(response);
            }
        });
}
```

My background script listens like this:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("received " + msg.type);
    if (msg.type = 'ACTIVITY_HISTORY_READY' && historyData) {
        if (historyData) {
            sendResponse({
                type: "HISTORY_DATA",
                position: historyData.position,
                company: historyData.company
            });
            historyData = '';
        } else {
            sendResponse({
                type: "NO_DATA"
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And the listener in my popup is:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {

    if (msg.type == 'JOB_DETAILS') {

        sendResponse("OK!");

        document.getElementById('position').value = msg.position;
        document.getElementById('company').value = msg.company;
        document.getElementById('url').value = sender.tab.url;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (msg.type = 'ACTIVITY_HISTORY_READY' && historyData) {
```

note that if `historyData` is falsey you are not sending any response. The `else` branch of the second `if` can never be taken.

You should remove `historyData` from the first `if`. The popup code has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Aaaaarrrgggghhhhh. Thank you. that fixed it. So much easier to blame Google.